# Clearing jQueryMobile DateBox value from an event

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I have 2 `DateBox` (from & to). What I want to do is whenever I click on the "from" `DateBox` it will always clear the "to" `DateBox`.

I'm looking at the `doclear` method and I'm not sure if it is the right one or even know how to use it.

Just to be clear I'm using [this](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my testing setting the value of the box to an empty string ('') works.
Assuming id of `fromDate` and `toDate`on the two boxes the following code should do the trick:

```
$('#fromDate').click(function(){
    $('#toDate').val('');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! didn't see it was that simple :)

Comment: No problem. I guess jQuery tries it best to make life easy for us :)